# Put Numbering labels for multiple camera objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have three js scene where there is a 3d model and i want to add multiple cameras to the model. To differentiate each of the cameras added to the scene i need to label the cameras with a number,may near the camera helper. Please advice how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, take a look at this example as to how you should have multiple cameras:
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_views.html

That code uses a singe camera whose parameters are updated for each different view, and a render call is performed for each view.

As to adding labels, a simple solution would be to simply overlay some HTML over the canvas, since you would know the position of each view. Have the HTML tag be placed on top of the canvas, and it will look just as the frame counter that is used in that example(if you examine the elements of that example, you will see what I mean).